Qt-6-based program needs libxcb-cursor.so.0 - but I don't have a package for that
I'm trying to use a Qt6-based program, namely NVIDIA's Nsight Compute UI, on a machine running SLES 15 SP5 (SUSE Enterprise Linux 2015, service pack 5). No, I can't switch distributions, it's not my decision :-(
Anyway, the program used to run fine in all its versions from 2023, but with more recent versions, I get:
 - Error: libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(for the long version, see below). Now, I can install packages on this machine, but - there is no libxcb-cursor package; there are a bunch of other libxcb-whatevers, but not that particular one.
So, how can I satisfy the library requirement for my application?

Long version of the error message:
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, wayland, offscreen, wayland-egl.

Application could not be initialized!
    This is likely due to missing Qt platform dependencies.
    For a list of dependencies, please refer to https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linux-requirements.html
    To view missing libraries, set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 and re-run the application.

Warning: OpenGL Version check failed. Falling back to Mesa software rendering.
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, wayland, offscreen, wayland-egl.

################# ERROR: CrashReporter #################
CrashReporter

Qt initialization failed

Failed to load Qt platform plugin: "xcb"
 - Library path: /opt/versions/nvidia/nsight-compute/2024.3/host/linux-desktop-glibc_2_11_3-x64/Plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
 - Error: libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please check if libxcb-cursor.so.0 has been installed on your system
See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linux-requirements.html for more details.
Application is going to abort
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
/opt/versions/nvidia/nsight-compute/2024.3/host/linux-desktop-glibc_2_11_3-x64/ncu-ui: line 26: 26176 Aborted  

